# Problema con Lista Genérica

Tags: java, nodos

Tengo el código funcionando, que copie del ejercicio, pero no lo entiendo (busqué videos y ejemplos en otros sitios pero agarran temas que todavía no manejo como Linkedlist, etc). El objetivo es crear una estructura de nodos en la que seamos capaces de insertar un nuevo nodo en una posición específica de la lista.

el código de dicho método es el siguiente:

```
public class ListaGenerica {

    class Nodo {
        int info;
        Nodo sig;
    }

    private Nodo raiz;

    public ListaGenerica () {
        raiz=null;
    }

void insertarEnMedio(int pos, int x) {

 if (pos <= cantidad () + 1)    {
            Nodo nuevo = new Nodo ();
            nuevo.info = x;
            if (pos == 1){
                nuevo.sig = raiz;
                raiz = nuevo;
            } else
                if (pos == cantidad () + 1)    {
                    Nodo reco = raiz;
                    while (reco.sig != null) {
                        reco = reco.sig;
                    }
                    reco.sig = nuevo;
                    nuevo.sig = null;


                } else {
                    Nodo reco = raiz;
                    for (int f = 1 ; f <= pos - 2 ; f++)
                        reco = reco.sig;
                    Nodo siguiente = reco.sig;
                    reco.sig = nuevo;
                    nuevo.sig = siguiente;
                }
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ListaGenerica lg= new ListaGenerica();
        lg.insertarEnMedio (1, 10);
        lg.insertarEnMedio (2, 20);
        lg.insertarEnMedio (3, 30);
        lg.insertarEnMedio (4, 40);
        lg.insertarEnMedio (5, 50);
        lg.insertarEnMedio (4 , 1 );
```

(aclaro que lo que no entiendo como funciona es la última línea de código cuando el nodo se inserta en el medio ("lg.insertarEnMedio (4,1)" ) y no al principio o al final que eso lo tengo claro )

Como dije el método funciona bien pero según mi lógica equivocada, tendría que dar como resultado el siguiente dibujo y no entiendo que es lo que estoy pensando mal.

como ven según mi entendimiento incorrecto de los nodos, el programa no funcionaría, quedando en la posición 3, el nodo que debería estar en la posición 4. Pero no entiendo que estoy pensando mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has reducido tanto el código que no has puesto dónde llamas a esa función `insertarEnMedio`, pero bueno. Imaginemos que llamas a la función en algún momento pasándole la posición `4`. Tu `for` dentro de la función no tiene sentido. Recorres desde `1` hasta `4-2`. ¿Cuál es el sentido de esto? Con `f = 1` apuntas `reco` al elemento con valor `20` (el segundo). Con `f=2` has terminado el bucle que termina cuando `f` valga `4 - 2 = 2`. Y lo insertas ahí. Si no entiendes el código, prueba a depurar paso a paso y verás como van avanzando tus nodos.

Comment: Ahí corregí el ejercicio tenías razón. Igual sigo sin entender pero estoy viendo como es eso de depurar.